# Deducing an html element via its adjacent values

Tags: python, html, css, xml, selenium

I have an html page that renders something similar to the following table:

```
nov.    service 1     [ click to download pdf ]
nov.    service 5     [ click to download pdf ]
nov.    service 3     [ click to download pdf ]
dec.    service 1     [ click to download pdf ]
dec.    service 9     [ click to download pdf ]
```

This is the html:

```
<tr class="values">
    <td class="col-1 first">Nov 2011</td>
    <td class="col-2">Switzerland</td>
    <td class="col-4">7</td>
    <td class="col-5">24.56</td>
    <td class="col-6">CHF</td>
    <input width="65" height="16" type="image" name="0.0.9.7.3.1.11.1.11.17.1.8.13.1.1" src="/itc/images/btn-grey-download.png" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="values">
    <td class="col-1 first">Nov 2011</td>
    <td class="col-2">United Kingdom</td>
    <td class="col-4">25</td>
    <td class="col-5">67.88</td>
    <td class="col-6">GBP</td>
    <input width="65" height="16" type="image" name="0.0.9.7.3.1.11.1.11.17.1.9.13.1.1" src="/itc/images/btn-grey-download.png" />
</tr>
<tr class="values">
    <td class="col-1 first">Oct 2011</td>
    <td class="col-2">Americas</td>
    <td class="col-4">14</td>
    <td class="col-5">2</td>
    <td class="col-6">USD</td>
    <input width="65" height="16" type="image" name="0.0.9.7.3.1.11.1.11.17.1.10.13.1.1" src="/itc/images/btn-grey-download.png" />
</tr>
```

I need to be able to 'select' and click all buttons that are in the month of nov (currently I'm using Selenium). I'm able to click a single button via the CSS selector (figured out through Firebug), but how would I do programmatically for all buttons in the month of nov? The psuedocode would be:

```
if tr.values.col-1.startswith(<month>):
    click the button in that row
```

Comment: Could you maybe add more information about the CSS selection that is currently working for one element and the html for the buttons you want to click on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Selenium, you may want to try selecting by XPath instead. This XPath expression will give you all the `<input>` elements in a row with Nov 2011 in the first column:

```
//td[@class='col-1 first']/text()[normalize-space()='Nov 2011']/parent::*/parent::*/td/input
```

Comment: Wow, that's a powerful feature. Thanks